# Construct a list of dictionary after matching two list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I have these two list of dicts like below:

```
src_dict = [{"id": 111, "name": "sam"}, {"id": 333, "name": "name_changed_to_not_ross"}, {"id": 444, "name": "jack"}]

dest_dict = [{"rec_id":"abc","fields":{"id":111,"name":"sam"}}, 
                {"rec_id":"pqr","fields":{"id":222,"name":"john"}},
                 {"rec_id":"xyz","fields":{"id":333,"name":"ross"}}]
```

I need to create an insert and update list but in different format. While creating update list I need to get corresponding value from both list of dicts. (using blhsing approach this is possible but not getting complete result)

```
ids = {d['fields']['id'] for d in dest_dict}
records_update = [d for d in src_dict if d['id'] in ids]
records_insert = [d for d in src_dict if d['id'] not in ids]
```

Here is the result

records_insert (this is good)

```
[{'id': 444, 'name': 'jack'}]
```

records_update (this is the issue)

```
[{'id': 111, 'name': 'sam'}, {'id': 333, 'name': 'ross'}]
```

This is the output I expect in the records_update:

records_update (expected output)

```
[{'rec_id': 'abc', 'fields': {'id': 111, 'name': 'sam'}},
 {'rec_id': 'xyz', 'fields': {'id': 333, 'name': 'name_changed_to_not_ross'}}]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just got the order wrong.

```
ids = {d['id'] for d in src_dict}
records_update = [d for d in dest_dict if d['fields']['id'] in ids]

>>> records_update
[{'rec_id': 'abc', 'fields': {'id': 111, 'name': 'sam'}}, {'rec_id': 'xyz', 'fields': {'id': 333, 'name': 'ross'}}]
```